# Error publishing app to app store using xamarin

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I have built a really simple app using VS and Zamarin. The app builds fine and publishes to archive fine.

[image]

But when I then try and push it to the app store I get the following error

[image]

I then saved the ipa file to my desktop and tried to push it into the app store using "Transporter" but then got the following error.

[image]

I have contacted Apple developer support. And to be honest, they have been brilliant. Until you mention the word MS or Xamarin. At which point they don't want to know.

Can anyone give me any advice or point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: have you created that app's ID in your developer account already?  [see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=macos#set-up-an-app-id-and-entitlements) Why do you have "1.1" in your bundle id?  The fact that you're using Xamarin should be irrelevant.

Comment: Yes I have to create the app ID in developer.apple.com I think I needed to create that before it would allow me to create certificates and profiles

Answer (score 0):

1. AppStore isn't allowed to push a .ipa file. You should use App Store Distribution channel.
   [Process.pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uHCQ.png)
2. Check on https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list that you already have an app with identifier co.uk (unless create it :)
   [Check this in Identifiers section.pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIzui.png)
3. After pushing the app you couldn't change your app bundle name. So if 1.1 in bundle identifier means app current version,  I'll advise not to do this way and remove digits in the bundle, because there are other fields for code and version.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. The problem came from having two app id's set up and then in https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/ I was using the wrong one. Changed it to the correct one and it all works.

Thanks

Comment: You can mark this answer as the right answer which will help more people with same problem:).